# What happens if two people have different knowledge about a state in a quantum mechanical system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem, quantum-measurements

Let’s say I measure the spin of an electron, but I don’t tell you what it is and you don’t measure it yourself. Does that change the wave function for you or does it remain the same either way? If it remains the same, can you still measure the particle as having opposite spin? How does that work?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The radically quantum mechanical perspective is that after you measure, I will describe you and the electron spin as being entangled, and in a superposition. When I measure the electron spin, both the spin and you (i.e. where you store the result) collapse onto the measurement outcome. See also [Wigner's friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend)

Comment: ... I would be surprised if this had not been asked/answered here previously.

Comment: ...then two observers assign to a system two different (mathematical) states, and hence make different predictions. Where is the problem? You can ask a similar thing in classical mechanics.

Comment: @TobiasFünke It is not all that simple, since once people compare their predictions, they might find contradictions. Also, note that if I observe that you measure a quantum system, I should (at least if I treat you as a quantum system) update my description to include you. The reduced state of the original quantum system (as described by me) *will* therefore have been affected.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, both states make different predictions. I did not discuss Wigner's friend here (and I don't read the question as such), I just "answered" the (title) question. I don't see any problem in assigning two different states, based on different knowledges. Of course, one cannot expect to have a good/the correct description without any reason. And this is the same as in classical mechanics.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I was more thinking about the *"If it [the description] remains the same, [then what]"* in the question -- this is indeed puzzling, and one *does* have to update the description. Of course, the same is true for classical probabilistic theories.

Comment: Always remember that people, just like any measurement apparatus, are themselves quantum objects that are described by the wavefunction / density matrix along with the system you’re measuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an ensemble of identical quantum systems prepared in a pure state $\psi$. Next a measurement occurs of an observable $A$ with two possibles outcomes $a$ and $a’$.

A measurement is an objective fact, independent of any observer, since it is a physical interaction with an instrument. As a consequence the state changes. Outcomes are irreversibly recorded at macroscopic level and produce physical events in spacetime (it does not matter if we know them or not).

How it changes may depend on the knowledge about the outcome in a probabilistic theory as QM is. We can assign different states to a single system according to the comparison ensemble we choose. This choice is made on the ground of our knowledge about the outcomes of the measurement.

Suppose that the post measurement states associated to the above outcomes are respectively  $\phi$ and $\phi’$ with respective probabilities $p$ and $p’$ with $p+p’=1$.

- If I know that a specific element of the ensemble has produced $a$, then I assign it the post measurement state $\phi$.
- If I do not know the outcome, I assign it the post measurement state
  given by the mixture

$$p|\phi\rangle\langle \phi|+ p’|\phi’\rangle\langle \phi’|.$$

Both possibilities are permitted, and the theory turns out to be consistent if I use it coherently with the made choice. That is because predictions in terms of probabilities to be compared with experimental frequencies refer to different post measurement ensembles. And the considered system simultaneously belongs to both them.

In the first case the system is viewed as part of the post measurement ensemble, sub ensemble of the initial one, which is associated to the outcome $a$.

In the second case, the same system, is viewed as part of the post measurement ensemble which coincides with the initial one and embodies both outcomes.

The objective fact is the measurement process which changes the state, in a nonunitary way, from a pure state to a mixture. (The nature of this process is not yet completely understood, and maybe it also includes a subjective part in terms of a partial trace on the instrument/environment quantum degrees of freedom.)

If we focus on an outcome, and we view the system as part of the corresponding sub ensemble,  we introduce a subjective effect, a choice, which is very often called the “state collapse” $\psi \to \phi$.

(All the discussion above relies upon the ensemble interpretation of the QM formalism. A different possibility is to think of the state $\psi$ as an objective property of a single quantum system, independently of any ensemble which may contain it. Today I do not like this perspective, even if I considered it the correct one in the past.)

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't the correct way be to describe the system *and* the other observer *jointly* in a mixed state? Otherwise, it is possible for both observers to obtain different outcomes for a measurement in the same basis.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your comment. However, yes if including in the count also the measurement instrument, we have joint  mixed states... There is a nice paper by P. Busch about measurement schemes discussing some these issues "No information without disturbance": Quantum limitations of Measurments (around 2007)

Answer (score 1):

Measuring is how people acquire this knowledge.

One person measures the spin of the electron with respect to a vertical axis. This returns an up or down value, and puts the electron in a spin up or down state. The other person doesn't know the state, but the electron still has a state.

Suppose the other person measures spin with respect to a vertical axis. Since the electron is in a spin up or down state, he would discover the same answer, and leave the electron in the same state.

Instead, suppose the other person measures spin with respect to a horizontal axis. This returns left or right and changes the system to a spin left or spin right state. The electron has changed. The first person no longer knows the state. He could repeat his measurement and get either up or down.

The Feynman Lectures uses these ideas to introduce quantum mechanics with the [Stern-Gerlach experiment](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_05.html).

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I was wondering more about how the wave function looked for person 2 after person 1 measures the system.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the basis of the 1st measurement, the electron is in a pure state:

$$ \chi_0 = \left[\begin{array}c a \\ b\end{array}\right]_1$$

with $||a||^2 + ||b||^2 = 1$.

You measure, and it goes to a eigenstate. With probability $||a||^2$, it becomes:

$$  \chi_1 = \left[\begin{array}c 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]_1$$

and similarly for the "down" state.

Now measurement number 2 has axis rotated by polar angle $\theta$ and azimuthal angle $\phi$, so in his basis:

$$ \chi_1 =  \left[\begin{array}c e^{-i\phi/2}\cos\theta/2 \\ e^{i\phi/2}\sin\theta/2\end{array}\right]_2$$

So the second measurement selects an eigenstate from that. Either
$ \chi_2 = \left[\begin{array}c 1 \\ 0\end{array}\right]_2$ or
$ \chi_2 = \left[\begin{array}c 0 \\ 1\end{array}\right]_2$, with appropriate probability.